# Screen output to PHP

Tags: php, unix, ubuntu, shell-exec

I have a PHP file with shell commands running through a screen, the commands run fine but I was wondering if there was a way to get this to output to PHP without writing to another file and reading it on PHP's end.

PHP - trace() is just a fancy print_r()

```
$cmd = 'ls -h /';
trace(shell_exec('screen -S output -p 0 -X stuff "`echo '.$cmd.'\'\r\n\'`"'));
```

Web output

```
NULL
```

Screen output

```
www-data@:/home/ubuntu$ ls -h /
bin   build  etc   initrd.img      lib         media  opt   root  selinux  sys  usr  vmlinuz
boot  dev    home  initrd.img.old  lost+found  mnt    proc  sbin  srv      tmp  var  vmlinuz.old
```

Any suggestions?

--Edit--

Certain commands aren't outputting directly, one of the reasons I'm using screen

PHP

```
$cmd = 's3ls';
trace(shell_exec('screen -S output -p 0 -X stuff "`echo '.$cmd.'\'\r\n\'`"'));
trace(shell_exec($cmd));
```

Web output

```
trace:NULL
trace:NULL
```

Screen

```
www-data@:/home/ubuntu$ s3ls
+---------------+--------------------------+
|     Name      |       CreationDate       |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| bucket        | 2012-05-31T13:08:51.000Z |
| bucket        | 2012-01-17T16:51:58.000Z |
| bucket        | 2012-03-31T11:19:54.000Z |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$output = shell_exec('ls -h /');`?

Comment: Why not executing your command directly with shell_exec or exec?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#refsect1-function.shell-exec-examples

Comment: I need to put it through a shell as part of the monitoring process, The actual command I want to run also shows no output when put through either, i'll edit my post to show that now.

Comment: Don't use `trace()` for this, use `var_dump()` instead!

Comment: Gives the same "NULL" output, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[void passthru ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

> The passthru() function is similar to the exec() function in that it
>   executes a command. This function should be used in place of exec() or
>   system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which
>   needs to be passed directly back to the browser. A common use for this
>   is to execute something like the pbmplus utilities that can output an
>   image stream directly. By setting the Content-type to image/gif and
>   then calling a pbmplus program to output a gif, you can create PHP
>   scripts that output images directly.

Though apparently it may be a bit flaky.

Comment: Thanks, before now i'd never heard of this function :D